# JVM crashes while trying to run Junit test case

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, java-8

While trying to run a Junit test case, eclipse crashes. 
Junit is using the same JRE as the workspace.
Worspace is using Oracles JVM jdk1.8.0_151.jdk as in the Eclipse.ini below
Logs show as below:

```
#A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff7dc97010, pid=2898, tid=0x0000000000000307
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_151-b12) (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_platform.dylib+0x5010]  _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell+0xf0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Not sure if this is related:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184898

If this is really the case, where do I add this param, in Eclipse.ini? Adding that didnt help either.

My Eclipse.ini looks like this:

```
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4048m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
```

Tried increasing the memory too. Didnt help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you narrow down the failure?

Comment: Can you run this from the command line. It will rule in/out eclipse issues

Comment: The trick is that this parameter needs to be passed to the JVM instance that will run the tests, assuming that you are indeed suffering from the reported bug. The configuration you changed is only for the JVM instance used to run Eclipse. You may have to set it in the Java runtime settings inside the Eclipse preferences.

Comment: A separate VM is used to execute a JUnit test case. Is Eclipse exited? If not, you have to edit the launch configuration of the JUnit test, not `eclipse.ini`.

Comment: @howlger: Yes, eclipse exits iwth a dialog showing some error like: Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000013aa00000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
VM Regions Near 0x13aa00000:
    VM_ALLOCATE            000000013a800000-000000013aa00000 [ 2048K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> VM_ALLOCATE         000000013aa0e000-000000013ae0e000 [ 4096K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV .

Comment: @user1059720 Can you reproduce this issue with Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a). From your `eclipse.ini` I can see you are using an outdated Eclipse version. See e. g. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502711

Comment: @Gimby I also added the parameter to my JRE settings Eclipse -> Preferences and also as VM argument to the test case. But didnt work.

Comment: @howlger: I did try with Oxygen, but it had several issues with JPA handlers and it was absolutely not usable, hence had to switch to latest Neon and it is fairly stable running on tomcat.

Comment: @user1059720 What does the Eclipse platform have to do with JPA handlers? How do you run Eclipse on TomCat? It seems your problem has been fixed months ago: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502711 (search for `libsystem_platform.dylib` and `_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell`)

Answer (score 0):

This is a **known issue which has already been fixed** in Eclipse Oxygen:

[Eclipse bug 502711 - [Cocoa][10.12] crashes on „macOS Sierra“ related to NSCopyBits](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502711)

[**Upgrading at least the Eclipse platform**](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F) should fix the problem.

Comment: I don't really see how that bug report has anything to do with running unit tests though. It seems that there are several paths that may lead to a crash report mentioning platform_memmove as the top stackframe.

Comment: @Gimby _"The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code."_  Running a JUnit test does not require native code. Running a JUnit test seems to be here correlation, not causality.